# How to Disable a SharePoint Multi-line Text Input Box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom SharePoint 2010 edit form and I need to disable a field rendering it read only.  I have tried the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
//Set the Field to Read only and change its background colour
//$("input[title='status_x0020_history']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
$("input[Title='status_x0020_history']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
</script>
```

The field name is status_x0020_history
Does position of the above code matter? it currently does not appear to impact my form.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    //Set the Field to Read only and change its background colour
    $("textarea[title='status history']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
   // $("textarea[Title='status history']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: NICE!!!
 
Will that still allow the scroll bars to work?

Comment: Which scroll bars? would you mind adding screen shots?

Comment: If you don't want scroll in your large text plain multi-line box on this case, just read the content from box and append to div after to box. hide the multi-line box there after. var content =  $("textarea[title='status history']").val(); $("textarea[title='status history']").hide().after('<div>'+content +'</div>');

Comment: No actually I do want scroll and if the data requires the user should be able to scroll down even though disabled

Comment: Ok, then set height and scroll for the div..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309268/set-div-height-auto-and-scroll-can-be-used

Comment: Hi @pinkstonmatt , Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answer as accepted in case it helped and solved your issue to be helpful for future visitors. If you still need additional clarification Please check this **[Disable SharePoint Multiline TextBox Field In Edit Form](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/disable-multiple-line-field-sharepoint)**